# Existe alguna libreria o metodo para javascript para impresora termica

Tags: php, javascript, imprimir, impresora

buen dia, quisiera imprimir en impresora POS, tickets o termica, tal cual como en este video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jlf4CuYm0l8
es decir, sin cuadro de impresion, de manera automatica ya que al haber muchas impresiones continuas, se gastaría mucho tiempo en mostrar y dar click en el cuadro de dialogo

existe alguna libreria o metodo para hacerlo desde javascript?

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Habilitar el navegador en modo kiosko te permite enviar a imprimir sin cuadros de diaglogo de confirmacion